# Fotorama Gallery - How to minimize the frame size for product base image

Tags: fotorama

I'm struggling to minimize the frame **width** and **height** for the product base image gallery (Fotorama).

I have inspected the browser code and noticed that if I change the following width and height the related Fotorama Frame size change however, did not found the actual location to customized the white border size (width and height):

```
<div class="fotorama__stage" data-fotorama-stage="fotorama_stage" style="**width: 707px; height: 707px;**">

<div class="fotorama__stage__shaft fotorama__grab" tabindex="0" data-gallery-role="stage-shaft" style="transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); margin-left: 0px; width: 707px;">
```

Basically when I change the above `width: 707px;` `height: 707px;` through browser inspect I can see the changes but no where found the actual file or location to change the value.

Answer (score 2):

In your theme > `app/design/frontend/package/theme-name/etc/view.xml` Inside `<media>` node you can define different image sizes:

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
        <width>300</width>
        <height>300</height>
    </image>
</images>
```

Please Change Option Value in

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
            "magnifierOpts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMagnifier(); ?>,
            "data": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>,
            "options": {
                "maxheight": "700", // Add your value here
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Moin Malek, it's only change the base image size not the frame or white border width & height. My only concern is to minimised the white extra space not the image size...

Comment: Hello @Alam Please Find edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggested code it is working for the height but not width. I wanted H: 515 and W: 515. Very appreciated.

Comment: @Alam : did you get the soln of width also. i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for the , after your value. Its not needed if you add it as the last option.

```
"options": {
                "something": "value",
                "maxheight": "700" // Add your value here
           }
```